# can't make matter.js start

Tags: javascript, html, css, matter.js

I was approaching the matter.js library but I couldn't even make it start. I followed thoroughly the "getting started" guide by I can't see the renderer appear. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```js
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>frist sketch matter js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/matter.js"></script>
    <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>First sketch</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are writing your own code in `sketch.js`, import it after the `matter.js` library in your HTML.

Comment: I've tried to do it but it still doesn't show up

Comment: Is the path ```/libraries/matter.js``` valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was probably caused by the fact that the javascript code was running before the page was loaded. So the method I found is to add this code to my js file: `window.addEventListener("load",init);` and then put all of the code I wrote into this function: `function init(){...}`

It seems to be working in this way, but I was wondering if there would be other better ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `style.css` refers to, but using cdn references for the Javascript files fixes the problem.

```js
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>frist sketch matter js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sketch.js/1.0/sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>First sketch</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put style.css because I wanted to use to style my page (even tho it was still empty). Can I ask you why using cdn to import the file sketch.js? am not I supposed to link the file in my folder project? Thanks

Comment: For packages like Sketch and Matter, you can use a CDN. For your own stylesheet, you need to save that to a web-accessible place on your site and make the url to it reference that website.

Comment: oh, actually Sketch is the name of the js file I was working on. is it the name of a package as well?